# Error of character use tesseract

Tags: c#

I use tessract-ocr:

```
 var image = new Bitmap(@"C:/Users/toshiba/Desktop/lettre.jpg");
                    var ocr = new Tesseract(); 
                    ocr.Init(@"C:\Users\toshiba\Desktop\ravo\tessdata", "eng", false);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_system_dawg", 0);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_freq_dawg", 0);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_punc_dawg", 0);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_unambig_dawg", 0);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_bigram_dawg", 0);
                    ocr.SetVariable("load_fixed_length_dawgs", 0);
                    var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
                    foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
                        //File.AppendAllText("", word.Text);
                    }
```

I receive letters but it looks different to the text on an image. What is wrong?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands your question would also be closed on [SO].

Answer (score 0):

tessract-ocr is not reading the words poperly.
This may be due to different font or the bad quality of the image.